# install CMake occurs a error, how to deal with it?

Tags: install-from-source

I am installing CMake in ubuntu, after did the last step "make install", This is the result:

```
-- Install configuration:""
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (FILE):
 file cannot create directory: /user/local/doc/cmake-2.8. Maybe need
 administrative privileges.

make: ***[install] Error 1
```

does it mean it didn't install successfully?

Answer (score 7):

Installation requires root privilages. So you have to use `sudo make install` Instead of `make install`

Answer (score 1):

You can install cmake under your home directory. To this end you simply need to run the bootstrap script as follows:

```
./bootstrap --prefix=$HOME
```

Then you do not need to use sudo command

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific requirement to run cmake version 2.8.9? Version 2.8.7 is available from the repositories and can be installed by running the command `sudo apt-get install cmake`

If you must compile a version yourself you will need to run the make install command as `sudo make install` as your application needs permissions to install itself into the filesystem.

To check for cmake files after compilation, run the command `sudo updatedb` and then `locate cmake`

Finally, run `cmake` from the command line, without any options, specified and you should get some output on using various command flags if the application compiled correctly.

**Update: rolled up previous comments into this answer.**

Comment: how to check it was installed ?

Comment: I use this method:                                               " ./configure –prefix=/opt/cmake" ---> "make" ----> "sudo make install" --->" /opt/cmake/bin/cmake -version"
It shows output: “cmake version 2.8.9”, is it means it install successful?@maggotbrain

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a path during `make`, then it will install to the specified directory. Then you must try with `sudo` to install to this particular directory as

```
sudo make install
```

If you don't select any prefix during `make`, then it will be installed in your current directory. In that case `sudo` is not required.