# how to check whether CMake is installed in ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [install CMake occurs a error, how to deal with it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225288/install-cmake-occurs-a-error-how-to-deal-with-it)

i installed the CMake in ubuntu, how to check if it installed ?

Comment: I believe that I was answering your original question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225288/install-cmake-occurs-a-error-how-to-deal-with-it/225290#comment278493_225290).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu One. Also, please don't re-post the same question multiple times. Once is enough. If you want cmake in Ubuntu, simply run `sudo apt-get install cmake` and you will have it installed.

Answer (score 44):

Just type `cmake --version` in terminal, If cmake is not installed you will command not found error, If cmake is installed , you can see the cmake version

Comment: I'n my case I also needed to know the version, so this was the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type as

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep cmake
```

If it was installed then you will get install message after them like below .

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep cmake
cmake                           install
cmake-data                      install

$
```

Hope that hlps .

credit goes Here :[http://www.howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/show-the-list-of-installed-packages-on-ubuntu-or-debian/)

Comment: Will this command work for manually compiled applications?

Comment: It won't work if cmake is installed from source

Comment: cool but " which cmake "
can help

Comment: Please remove the dot from the code line, it is literally wrong!

Comment: dot removed, bad image replaced with text.