# uninstall cmake in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: uninstall, cmake

I need to uninstall cmake from my Ubuntu machine.
I tried via command line as I saw in [How can I uninstall software in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software?newreg=806b4d6361a74323a8dd202f2afa66dd)

```
sudo apt-get remove cmake
sudo apt-get purge cmake
sudo apt remove cmake
```

But it didn't worked, the cmake is still exist in `~/.local/bin` dir and when I check the version [how to check whether CMake is installed in ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225579/how-to-check-whether-cmake-is-installed-in-ubuntu)

```
cmake --version
```

I get the cmake version .
How can I uninstall and remove cmake?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: **why** do you need to uninstall `cmake`?

Comment: I upgraded tn cmake to version 3.17.0, the new version doesn't back compatibility and some of my projects didn't build, so for now I decided to remove it and reinstall it with the default version that comes with `sudo apt-get install cmake`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is absolutely normal that `~/.local/bin` folder is not maintained by APT.

Remove the file with:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/bin/cmake
```

and retry running `which cmake` or `cmake --version` to confirm its removal.